# DrawerLayout in a LinearLayout bad placement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm a new developper Android and my issues is, I would like to have my DrawerLayout in all the left of my activity and as his parent Layout his height = "50 dip", my Navigation Drawer do the same size, I don't know how I can put my Drawer Layout for a good placement in my Activity (above all the composant) but at the same place in action bar for the navigation user.

I cleaned up the code

```
   <LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/include_splash" />

    <LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip">

            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                    android:layout_width="240dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="#333"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:divider="#666"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15sp"
                    android:paddingRight="15sp"
                    android:paddingTop="15sp" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/i_v_logo_accueil" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_w_rubrique_accueil" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/i_b_reload_accueil"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/include_pub" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l_l_articles_accueil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/l_v_articles_accueil" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/r_l_videos_accueil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/l_v_videos_accueil"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l_l_evenements_accueil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/l_v_evenements_accueil" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l_l_magazines_accueil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/l_v_magazines_accueil" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="@color/line" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```